# c# regular expression to find "[data]" and the text that follows

Tags: c#, expression

Hi if anyone can help am new to regular expressions, and i have done some basic examples but nothing that i need.
This is my text file that i need to read:

```
[data]
84  73  0   -124    0   50
84  73  0   -124    0   50
84  84  0   -124    0   50
87  109 0   -124    0   50
82  120 0   -124    0   50
82  132 0   -124    0   50
83  143 0   -124    0   50
83  154 0   -124    0   50
```

My current code reads in the text file and stores it into a list i just need an expression that detects the `[data]` header and then starts to read all the information after the `[data]` until the end or preferably until it reaches `\r\n` just in case there is ever more data in the text file for example.
I am not asking anyone to do my code i have all the rest done, just the expression or a point in the right direction.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: what does "starts to read all the information" mean? what is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by, "...and stores it into a list?" Are we talking a `List<string>` here? If so, then if it's in a List, why do you need a regex?

Comment: you can read your file line by line an skip the first line if it contains "[data]"

Comment: File.ReadLines : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: I don't see any point in using regular expression here.

Comment: You say in your question "preferably until it reaches \r\n just in case there is ever more data in the text file for example", but looking from your example, it seems that there are several lines of data.  Wouldn't stopping at `\r\n` miss a lot of the data?

Comment: Reading text file and regular expressions! Why? I'm guessing that you source of problem is that you insist to use regular expressions (it's trendy).

Comment: You should edit your question. The sample data in the question contains new lines, but your real data does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the shortest regular expression that will do what you want, but I think it works `(\[data\]{1}\s*(\d+\s*|(\-{1})\d+\s*)+\n)`. I used http://regexpal.com/ to test the above regular expression using:

```
[data] 123  73 0 -124 21312 123 73 0 -123 231231
123
```

as test data.

Comment: thank you very much exactly what i was after. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regular expression when you can use `FilereadLines` and `Linq`:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("text.txt");
var result = lines.SkipWhile(i => i != "[data]").Skip(1);
```

Comment: Thank you this works but only if there is no other text below the [data]
84  73  0   -124    0   50
84  73  0   -124    0   50
84  84  0   -124    0   50
87  109 0   -124    0   50
82  120 0   -124    0   50
82  132 0   -124    0   50
83  143 0   -124    0   50
83  154 0   -124    0   50

Comment: What other text might be there?

Comment: this will be above the [data] StartTime=14:33:45.0
Length=00:49:34.2
Interval=1
Upper1=0
Lower1=0
Upper2=0
Lower2=0 and comments will be below which is separated by \r\n

Comment: So there is an empty line after the last `83  154 0   -124    0   50` (data line)?